# Regex to match ResourceBundle

Tags: java, regex, resourcebundle

I need a regular expression that will match the file name of a `ResourceBundle`, which follows the format `name_lo_CA_le.properties`. It should only match bundles that have a locale portion in their file names, and the name portion shall have no underscores.

After hours of experimentation I came up with the following:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(_([a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{0,2})?|[a-z]{0,2}(_[A-Z]{2})?){1}(_\\w*)?){1}\\.properties$
```

It doesn't seem to work for all cases:

```
"bundle.properties".match(...);               // false - correct
"bundle_.properties".match(...);              // false - correct
"bundle_en.properties".match(...);            // true - correct
"bundle__US.properties".match(...);           // true - correct
"bundle_en_US.properties".match(...);         // true - correct
"bundle_en__Windows.properties".match(...);              // false!
"bundle__US_Windows.properties".match(...);   // true - correct
"bundle_en_US_Windows.properties".match(...); // true - correct
```

I have absolutely no idea how to proceed from here. Here's my reasoning behind the parenthesized part:

`(...){1}` matches exactly one locale portion.

`(_([a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{0,2})?|[a-z]{0,2}(_[A-Z]{2})?){1}` matches exactly one of either a two-character language code and a possibly-zero-and-at-most-2-character country code or the other way around.

`(_\\w*)?` matches one or no variant.

Any idea how to fix and/or improve this regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Regex I ended up using:

```
^[a-zA-Z.]+(_([a-z]{2}(_[A-Z]{0,2})?|[a-z]{0,2}(_[A-Z]{2})?){1}(_\w*)?)\.properties$
```

It still doesn't match a locale portion with no country, as in `bundle_en__Windows.properties`, but it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

This matched all the examples:

```
^[a-zA-Z\_\.]+[A-Z]{0,2}[a-zA-Z\_\.]*.properties$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
^[a-zA-Z\_\.]+[A-Z]{2}[a-zA-Z\_\.]*.properties$
```

Comment: Yours seem to fail on `_en` and `_en__Windows`, just like mine.

Comment: Mmm, you forgot the .properties in the example of this case "bundle_en__Windows".match(...);

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that. I need this regex precisely to eliminate the need to list the locales in code. :) The regex determines which files to check, so I need one that would match every possible locale string. It appears mine is matching everything but `bundle_.properties` now, got any idea why?

Comment: @Matheus Moreira Ok, i think i got it, just putted the _ outside the locale part of the regex. At list it works in [link](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: You're escaping the DOT inside character classes (where they don't need escaping), and didn't escape it outside it! (check the DOT before `properties`)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "^[a-zA-Z]+(_)([a-z]{2})?(_)?([A-Z]{2})(_)?(\\w*)(\\.properties)$";

    assert "bundle.properties".matches(regex) == false;               // false - correct
    assert "bundle_.properties".matches(regex) == false;              // false - correct
    assert "bundle_en.properties".matches(regex) == false;            // false!
    assert "bundle__US.properties".matches(regex) == true;           // true - correct
    assert "bundle_en_US.properties".matches(regex) == true;         // true - correct
    assert "bundle_en__Windows".matches(regex) == false;             // false!
    assert "bundle__US_Windows.properties".matches(regex) == true;   // true - correct
    assert "bundle_en_US_Windows.properties".matches(regex) == true; // true - correct
  }
}
```

Comment: `_en` and `_en__Windows` should be `true`.